# TestNG BeforeClass and AfterMethod equivalent methods for TestNG listener

Tags: java, annotations, automated-tests, testng, testrail

Taking the below `base class methods testSetup() and getStatusAndAnnotation()` and putting them into TestNG Listener. I could find the equivalent of `@BeforeClass` as `onBeforeClass(ITestClass, IMethodInstance)`. However, what is the equivalent for `@AfterMethod`?

My aim is to pass the ITestResult as a parameter to that method because I will be holding the test result into it. The code below shows that I am getting the annotation and status of test and then pushing it to the testrail cloud. I tried using:

```
@Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod, ITestResult) {
        ..
    }
```

It did not help and gave

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: client.test.reporting.listeners.TestRailListener.test_getVersion()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1670)
```

Here Java: 1670 is

```
 throw new NoSuchMethodException(getName() + "." + name + argumentTypesToString(parameterTypes));
```

---

```
**@BeforeClass
        public static void testSetup() throws InterruptedException, IOException, APIException {
            initTestRail();
        }
@AfterMethod
public void getStatusAndAnnotation(ITestResult result) throws NoSuchMethodException, IOException, APIException {
    HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    Method m = getClass().getMethod(result.getName());
    TestCase annotation = m.getAnnotation(TestCase.class);
    try {
        map.put("testRailCaseId",annotation.testRailCaseId());
    }catch (NullPointerException e){}
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        map.put("result", 1);
    } else {
        map.put("result", 5);
    }
    if(annotation.testRailDeployEnable() && !map.get("testRailCaseId").equals(null) && !map.get("testRailCaseId").toString().isEmpty())
    {
        TestRailIntegration.addTestResult(map);
    }
    else System.out.println("Deploying result was canceled, because test has annotation \"testRailDeployEnable: false\" or \"testRailCaseId\" has no value");
}**
```

After every method is executed, whatever maybe the status (PASS/FAIL/SKIP), I want to execute this getStatusAndAnnotation...() but it gives above exception/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement `org.testng.ITestListener`, but instead of single method `afterInvocation()` it has several depending on the result: `onTestSuccess()`, `onTestFailure()`, `onTestSkipped()`, etc. Every method is passed `ITestResult` object, which also contains method being executed:

`@Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        Method method = iTestResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
        Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        ...
    }`

Comment: I have used "Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();" and this worked for me. Thanks!